# Android, how to close progress bar in onPageFinished() method of setWebViewClient()?

Tags: android, webview, progress-bar

In my activity, I have a Webview. I need to show Loading (progress bar) when webview is loading the page and closing progress bar when loading of page is finished. I have written following code:

```
wvBrowser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

                progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(F1TrackCountryRaceTrackInfo.this, "", "Loading...");
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);

                progressBar.dismiss();
            }
        });
```

When I run the app for first time everything is fine however for second time application crashes and logcat points to "`progressBar.dismiss();`" in "onPageFinished".

I added "onPause()" method in order to close the activity and thought that maybe it solve the problem but I still have same problem.

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if(progressBar.isShowing())
            progressBar.dismiss();

        Toast.makeText(this, "Activity closed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        F1TrackCountryRaceTrackInfo.this.finish();
    }
```

What is my mistake and how to solve it? Thanks

Logcat error:

> 04-03 11:14:36.880: E/AndroidRuntime(19613): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   04-03 11:14:36.880: E/AndroidRuntime(19613):
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 04-03 11:14:36.880:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(19613):  at
>   com.maxis.f12011.activities.F1TrackCountryRaceTrackInfo$1.onPageFinished(F1TrackCountryRaceTrackInfo.java:75)
>   04-03 11:14:36.880: E/AndroidRuntime(19613):  at
>   android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:289)
>   04-03 11:14:36.880: E/AndroidRuntime(19613):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 04-03
>   11:14:36.880: E/AndroidRuntime(19613):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130) 04-03 11:14:36.880:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(19613):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691) 04-03
>   11:14:36.880: E/AndroidRuntime(19613):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 04-03
>   11:14:36.880: E/AndroidRuntime(19613):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 04-03 11:14:36.880:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(19613):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
>   04-03 11:14:36.880: E/AndroidRuntime(19613):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665) 04-03
>   11:14:36.880: E/AndroidRuntime(19613):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 0):

I exported "`progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(F1TrackCountryRaceTrackInfo.this, "", "Loading...");`" from onPageStarted() and put it in oncreate() method and the problem solved.
Now each time activity started loading will show untill webview load the page and then onPageFinished() closes the loading bar.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is here like `onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)` method is called once for each main frame load so a page with iframes or framesets will call onPageStarted one time for the main frame. This also means that onPageStarted will not be called when the contents of an embedded frame changes, i.e. clicking a link whose target is an iframe. [see here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageStarted%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String,%20android.graphics.Bitmap%29)

So progressbar is instantiating only for first time , next time it is not instantiating. Problem is calling dismiss() on null.

Answer (score 0):

try this it work fine..

```
private WebView webview;
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {       
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.abc);




        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

         dialog = new ProgressDialog(classname.this);
          dialog.setMessage("Loading......");
          dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
          dialog.setCancelable(true);
          dialog.show();

        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);       
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebviewUrl());
        webview.loadUrl(your url here...);
    }   


    public class WebviewUrl extends WebViewClient  
    {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
        {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
             if (dialog.isShowing())
             {
                dialog.dismiss();
              }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it didn't work, same crash happened.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but this is how I made it work.

Create and setup the Progress Bar and WebView:

```
private WebView myWebView;
private ProgressBar myProgressBar;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(activity_web);

    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.ib_web_wv_main);
    myProgresBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.ib_web_progressbar);

}
```

Make the progress bar VISIBLE and INVISIBLE when needed:

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon){

         myProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   }

   @Override
   public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
           myProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

    });
```

Answer (score -1):

try place `progressBar.dismiss();` before `super.onPageFinished(view, url);` in `onPageFinished` method.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but unfortunately it didn't work and same crash happened.